# Cleaning/Washing hands in plate after meals

Tags: source-identification, sunnah

I have seen two different groups of people who say cleaning hands in the plate after a meal is considered sunnah due to which Shaytan will not sit on the plate. Whereas the second group of people say you should not clean your hands in the plate after a meal otherwise [Barakah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barakah) will be gone.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

There's no Sahih hadith that mentions either of the two.  The only thing that speaks about cleaning hands are the one's mentioning to lick the finger before wiping them.

Jabir reported Rasolullah said =

> **"Indeed Shaitan is with you in everything one does. He is there even when you eat food.  So if any of you drops a morsel he should remove
>   any filth on it and eat it and not leave for Shaitan.  And when you
>   finish (your food), you should lick your fingers, for one does not
>   know in what portion of his food the blessing lies."**

[Sahih Muslim - Book of Drinks]

I did a search throughout 9 hadith books and couldn't really find anything that you mention.  This was the closest I would say.

Allaho Alim.

Comment: Yup, these kind of statements mentioned in OP's question sometimes come from culture and then gets mixed up as teaching of Islam.